# Can codemirror find textareas by class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, codemirror

**A good start**

I asked this question "[Codemirror - Use on multiple textareas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480137/codemirror-use-on-multiple-textareas)" a few years ago with a good answer. However, it still takes an ID as parameter. IDs are unique.

**Find textarea by class instead of ID**

When having multiple textareas, some with HTML and some with CSS on the same page, it would be nice to add a class instead of an ID.

**Example**

```
<p>Some content</p>

<textarea class="my_codemirror_html">
</textarea>

<p>Some content</p>

<textarea class="my_codemirror_html">
</textarea>'
```

If I can use jQuery for it, it's fine. I use that anyway on the page.

**Update 2012-02-21 - Almost there**

I found this post on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mofle/tZVsS/). The only thing missing is that I can't make it work on textareas.

Comment: You can do that yes. Your selector would be:

textarea.my_codemirror_html {

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved it by adding an ID with jQuery to all textareas.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var code_type = '';
            $('.code-html').each(function(index) {
                $(this).attr('id', 'code-' + index);
                CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code-' + index), {
                        mode: "text/html",
                        lineNumbers: true,
                        tabMode: "indent"
                    }
                );

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 14):

This will be an easier solution with **less complexity**.

```
$('.my_codemirror_html').each(function(index, elem){
      CodeMirror.fromTextArea(elem, {/*options*/});
});
```

Comment: This should be the answer in my opinion, couldn't find any better solution than this. And its less complex than the marked answer

Answer (score 2):

All javascript version:

```
var codemirrorInstance = [];
var foundtextareasarr = document.getElementsByClassName('classForTextareas');
for(var i = 0; foundtextareasarr[i]; ++i) { 
  codemirrorInstance[i] = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(foundtextareasarr[i], {
    lineNumbers: true,
    mode: "add-your-mode-here"     
  });
}
```

The code above will find all textareas by class and convert them into individual codemirror instances using only javascript and not jQuery.