# <f:ajax render="@all" /> does not work in production evnironment

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, codemirror

In a jsf 2.2 application I have a form that has this tag

```
<h:inputTextarea id="code_editor_demo_1" value="#{testBean.question.code}" />
```

I use the id `"code_editor_demo_1"` so that a javascript plugin called **CodeMirror** format the textarea to this:

[image]

Now There is a button called **“next”** for navigation

```
<h:commandButton id="nextBtn" styleClass="btn default col-sm-offset-1" value="Next" action="#{testBean.nextQuestion}" >
    <f:ajax render="@all" />
</h:commandButton>
```

The method `nextQuestion()` does some processing and has a return type of void.
Now on my local environment when I click next, the page is re-rendered to show new values + The plugin Codemirror is Re-Applied to the textarea.

On the production environment however (Application hosted on Cloud Paas, DB on AWS), the method get invoked BUT the UI is **NOT** updated, the ajax call to re-render @all does not happen.

I have tried:

Replacing @all with two specific id of `<div jsf:id>..` it works, the new values are shown correctly **EXCEPT** that the codemirror plugin does not format the `<h:inputTextarea id="code_editor_demo_1" value="#{testBean.question.code}" />` to be displayed like in the picture above. That’s Why I have to use @all, because it’s the only value that re-apply the plugin on the textarea.

Note: the plugin works by specifying the id to `“code_editor_demo_1”`

Why is that? And how Can I fix this? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

As the user **@Kukeltje** suggested, I did found the Javascript method that re-apply the codemirror plugin on the textarea.

```
<h:commandButton id="nextBtn" styleClass="btn default col-sm-offset-1" value="Next" action="#{testBean.nextQuestion}" >    
    <f:ajax render="pass-section ads-section" onevent="handleDemo1"/>    
</h:commandButton>
```

JS handledemo

```
var ComponentsCodeEditors = function () {

var handleDemo1 = function () {
    var myTextArea = document.getElementById('code_editor_demo_1');
    var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(myTextArea, {
        lineNumbers: true,
        matchBrackets: true,
        styleActiveLine: true,
        theme:"ambiance",
        mode: 'javascript'
    });
}


return {
    //main function to initiate the module
    init: function () {
        handleDemo1();
    }
};
}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
   ComponentsCodeEditors.init(); 
});
```

However, the page that have this code is called test.xhtml and it always have a paramaeter called id . for example test.xhtml?id=5 .

The problem I’m encountering now is that After I click the next Btn (that execute the ajax part). The id parameter part of the url get removed, so instead of **test.xhtml?id=5** the url change to **test.xhtml** .

Any Idea how Can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You can also reapply the codemirror plugin on the  `f:ajax onevent`. No need to use '@all'

Comment: You mean ? <h:commandButton id="nextBtn" styleClass="btn default col-sm-offset-1" value="Next" action="#{testBean.nextQuestion}" >
    <f:ajax onevent="???" />
</h:commandButton> what value should onevent take ??

Comment: a javascript function name... Google is your friend

Comment: Ok I will search this. Thanks

Comment: @Kukeltje Would please take a look at the update above?

Comment: New questions in new questions please. And please create an answer for your first question instead of putting it in an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem with the help of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41794426/4255756 by [Muzafar Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41794426/4255756). Here is How I solve it
Created a new Javascript file with this content

```
function qsa(sel) {
    return Array.apply(null, document.querySelectorAll(sel));
}
function apply_code_mirror() {
    qsa(".code-mirror").forEach(function(editorEl) {
        CodeMirror.fromTextArea(editorEl, {
            lineNumbers : true,
            matchBrackets : true,
            styleActiveLine : true,
            theme : "ambiance",
            mode : 'javascript'
        });
    });
}
```

Added the file as a resource + a call to the js method.

```
<h:outputScript library="custom" name="codemirror/apply-as-class.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    apply_code_mirror();
</script>
```

The textarea becomes

```
<h:inputTextarea styleClass="code-mirror" value="#{display.question.code}" />
```

And When I want to re-apply codemirror on a textarea because of an ajax update I use

```
<h:commandButton id="nextBtn" styleClass="btn default col-md-offset-1" value="Next" action="#{testBean.nextQuestion}" >
    <f:ajax render="pass-section ads-section" onevent="apply_code_mirror"/>
</h:commandButton>
```