# codemirror - multiple text areas not working

Tags: javascript, codemirror

As per the question here [Can codemirror be used on multiple textareas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480137/can-codemirror-be-used-on-multiple-textareas).

I have applied the exact config to my page and neither text areas are being converted to code mirrors.

there are no errors in the console either, im not sure what ive missed?

my code is as follows:

```
<script src="{% static 'home/scripts/codemirror/codemirror.js' %}"></script>
<link href="{% static 'home/scripts/codemirror/codemirror.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{% static 'home/scripts/codemirror/django/django.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function editor(id) {
        CodeMirror.fromTextArea(id, {
            height: "400px",
            continuousScanning: 500,
            lineNumbers: true
        });
    }
editor('id_config');
editor('id_remote_config');
</script>
<form id="edit_template" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ TemplateForm.template_name }}
    {{ TemplateForm.config }}
    {{ TemplateForm.remote_config }}
    <input type='submit' value='Update' />
</form>
```

the django form renders the text areas with the IDs I have specified

[image: text area ids]

anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those textareas don't exist at the time you call `editor()`. Either move your script tag below the form or call `editor()` inside a window load event handler

Comment: I moved everything in <script>...</script> underneath the form, still nothing?

Comment: Errors in browser console?

Comment: TypeError: textarea.getAttribute is not a function. (In 'textarea.getAttribute("autofocus")', 'textarea.getAttribute' is undefined) - in codemirror 9512

Comment: added the below, it works var config = editor(document.getElementById('id_config'));
    var remote_config = editor(document.getElementById('id_remote_config'));